# deb version is "git tag+git commit hash" = apt downloading the wrong version from my apt repo

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg, deb, version

I made a [script](https://github.com/Itai-Nelken/box86-2deb-weekly-script) that compiles a program ([box86](https://github.com/ptitSeb/box86)), packages it into a debian package every week, and uploads it to my [apt repo](https://github.com/Itai-Nelken/weekly-box86-debs) (hosted on github).
for the version of each package I use the git tag (`0.2.1` for example) and the git commit hash (`638b341` for example) and put them like this: tag+sha1 (`0.2.1+638b341` for example). note that checkinstall that is used for packaging adds a `-1` to the end, so in my example, the version would be `0.2.1+638b341-1`.

after adding the repo to my apt sources, apt gets the wrong version. I tried several fixes including adding a "epoch", incrementing the `-1`, and adding a number before and incrementing it in each version (`1-version`). but none of them worked (or would be practical).

I'm pretty sure I have to add something to the version, but I don't know what.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: What version does `apt` get?

Comment: @StephenKitt as of now the available versions are:  `0.2.1+044326d3-1`, `0.2.1+13cce1a4-1`, `0.2.1+638b341b-1`, `0.2.1+e478b993-1`, 
and `0.2.1+f370bf77-1`. the latest is: `0.2.1+638b341b-1`.

apt downloads: `0.2.1+13cce1a4-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All else being equal, `apt` prefers later versions. Because hashes don’t increase with time, using them in versions can cause the problem you’re seeing.

There are two common workarounds: [adding a monotonically-increasing number before the hash](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/tesseract-lang), or [adding the date, again before the hash](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/vcmi).

Taking the latter approach, for a build done today you’d have 0.2.1+20210320.thehash-1, replacing “thehash” as appropriate. Better yet, you can use

```
git log --date=format:%Y%m%d --pretty=0.0~git%cd.%h
```

to generate the version number; this is supported by [`uscan`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/devscripts/uscan.1) and can be used to automatically update to the current head of a git repository.

Comment: what is the `date` command to get the current date in that format?

Comment: found a way: `date +"%F" | sed 's/-//g'`

Comment: that didn't work, apt still gets `0.2.1+13cce1a4-1` instead of `0.2.1+20210320.638b341b-1`

Comment: I deleted all the old builds because I think the where conflicting, I hope that from now on it will work.

Comment: Yes, all versions need to follow this pattern for it to work in all cases (until you update the main version, *e.g.* 0.2.2-1 for a proper 0.2.2 release). 0.2.1+13cce1a4-1 sorts lower than 0.2.1+20210320.638b341b-1 so the behaviour you’re getting is still surprising...

Comment: I made a build today and apt downloaded it even though it was the same commit hash as yesterday, so it works.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ItaiNelken if you change the version scheme, you might want to change the epoch number so that versions in the old scheme never sort after versions in the new scheme.

Comment: @muru I moved all the old builds (there where only a few, so no big deal) so no need for that. but thanks for the tip!